# Exception in JSON parsing: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT?

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, gson

I am trying to parse [**the JSON response from this link**](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=ptt&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyB-xhzVvONSDV7ZoAPt0QrP1bsOMRUhKms) and I'm getting this exception:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT
```

I have created this class to encapsulate the JSON data:

```
public class PlacesTextSearch {

    private String icon;
    private String name;
    private String types;
    private String formatted_address;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String id;

    public PlacesTextSearch(String icon,String name,String types,String formatted_address,double latitude,double longitude) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setIcon(icon);
        setName(name);
        setTypes(types);
        setFormatted_address(formatted_address);
        setLatitude(latitude);
        setLongitude(longitude);
    }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getIcon() {
            return icon;
        }
        public void setIcon(String icon) {
            this.icon = icon;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getTypes() {
            return types;
        }
        public void setTypes(String types) {
            this.types = types;
        }
        public String getFormatted_address() {
            return formatted_address;
        }
        public void setFormatted_address(String formatted_address) {
            this.formatted_address = formatted_address;
        }
        public Double getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }
        public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
        }
        public Double getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }
        public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }
}
```

And this is my code to parse the JSON:

```
private ArrayList<PlacesTextSearch> arrayListPlaces;       
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<PlacesTextSearch>>(){}.getType();
arrayListPlaces=new Gson().fromJson(response,listType);
```

---

Here you can see the complete exception stacktrace:

[image: Complete exception stacktrace]

Comment: apparently you are trying to load a json object into an array. may be you could post the actual json thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read [Gson documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) before trying to write your code? Have you even taken a look at [JSON structures](http://www.json.org/)?

Your code has many errors... The point is that you have to create a Java class structure that matches your JSON structure. And in fact, your class structure is not even similar to the JSON you want to parse! Basically where there's an object `{ }` in your JSON you have to use a class, and where there's an array in your JSON `[ ]` you have to use an array or a `List`...

According to your `PlacesTextSearch` class, I guess the JSON piece you want to parse is:

```
{    
  ...,
  "results" : [
    {
      "formatted_address" : "Zeytinlik Mh., Bakırköy/İstanbul, Türkiye",
      "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
          "lat" : 40.9790040,
          "lng" : 28.8730110
        }
      },
      "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
      "id" : "e520b6e19bae5c014470989f9d3405e55dce5155",
      "name" : "PTT",
      "types" : [ "post_office", "finance", "establishment" ]
      ...
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

So, how do you pretend to parse this into an `ArrayList<PlacesTextSearch>`!? That's not what your JSON represents! Do you really not see it?

Try something like this class structure (*pseudo-code*):

```
class Response
  List<PlacesTextSearch> results;

class PlacesTextSearch
  String formatted_address;
  Geometry geometry;
  String icon;
  String id;
  String name;
  List<String> types;

class Geometry
  Location location;

class Location
  long lat;
  long lng;
```

And parse it with:

```
Response response = new Gson().fromJson(response, Response.class);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot put some codes into my question.
I get results from my JSON with this code 

object = new JSONObject(response);
array = object.getJSONArray("results");

i am not trying to get all things. But you are right,  forgetting somethings is my fault. Thank you for answer

Comment: @EmreKoç: If you use my simple class structure it should be working for you, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it should work but i dont need all data which is coming from JSON. I just need results and i modified my code for this